# Isomorphism classes of lattices

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, lattices, euclidean-lattices, diophantine-geometry

Suppose we have a $4 \times 6$ matrix $A$ of rank $4$ whose entries are rational numbers. Define 
$$
V = \{x \in \mathbb R^6 \mid A \cdot x = 0\}
$$
and 
$$
\Lambda = \{x \in \mathbb Z^6 \mid A \cdot x = 0\}. 
$$
Equip $\mathbb R^6$ with the standard Euclidean metric and let $V$ inherit that metric from $\mathbb R^6$. Is there a sensible notion of the isomorphism class of the pair $(V, \Lambda)$? And how would this notion depend on the choice of the metric?

Comment: Let A be the order 4 identity matrix with a couple of zero columns adjoined.  Then V looks like a 2-dimensional plane in the 6-space with the points having the first four coordinates all zero. The lattice looks like the appropriate sublattice. Use elementary row operations on A, and see how V and the sublattice change accordingly.  If there is any nontrivial notion of isomorphism type, a combination of row operations will reveal it. Gerhard "Looks Like Planes To Me" Paseman, 2018.07.13.